# Is goto as powerful as comefrom?

Tags: language-agnostic, goto, comefrom

I just wondered if the hated `goto` statement is as powerful as the `comefrom` statement? In my opinion they are probably equal in their capabilities but I am not entirely sure on that. Is there any formal proof that they are equally powerful (or not equally powerful)?

---

For any who never heard of it: `comefrom` is sort of a reversed `goto`:

```
    comefrom doom;
    WriteLine("I will never stop executing!");
doom:
```

Comment: I feel pretty sure it's just syntactic sugar, (assuming labels are unique and each label can have at most one comefrom).

Comment: **That's a joke, ah say, that's a joke, son.** The `comefrom` statement was a humorous early-1970s response to Dijkstra's famous call for `goto`-less programming.

Comment: FYI: Exception handling has been labelled as a comefrom statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`comefrom` is strictly more powerful than `goto`.

Each program with `goto` can be mechanically transformed into an equivalent `comefrom`-only program, by, well, replacing each `goto` with a corresponding `comefrom`.

The reverse is not true. This program has no goto-only equivalent:

```
  doom:

  comefrom doom;
  WriteLine("I will never stop executing!");
  goto doom;

  comefrom doom;
  WriteLine("Guess my time has come!");
```

This program print the first phrase an unknown number of times, then the second phrase, and exit. This kind of non-determinism is not achievable with conventional programming languages that lack `comefrom`.

Comment: Strictly speaking that program has a goto-only counterpart. `doom:goto bang;bang:writeline("never stop");goto doom;bang:writeline("time has come")` That the compiler/assembler/interpreter will complain that there are two `bang` labels is just a language spec issue the same as your comefrom example. Not all languages with comefrom behave the way you describe. In a similar manner you can always define another programming language that allows multiple labels that behaves non-deterministically the way your comefrom works.

Comment: I thought that `comefrom` could be used only with a given label only once. But `comefrom doom;` appears twice in this example - what does that mean? Are you implying that, each time is execution reaches `doom:`, it will arbitrarily select from the two possibilities?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid This is one possible interpretation, I've seen it in INTERCAL "literature" (whatever it is).

Comment: Early versions of INTERCAL only allowed one `comefrom` statement for each label.  This requirement was relaxed with multi-threading support was added.